# Unable to find android.view in NativeScript

Tags: angular, nativescript

I am developing a native script app using angular, and I need to access the native Android API. I tried to use `android.view` as mentioned in the native script documentation, but I get an error saying that view is not defined : [Native Script documentation](https://docs.nativescript.org/runtimes/android/metadata/accessing-packages)

Here below is the declaration used to access the android object.

```
import { android } from "application";
```

Can you help me please to find out why am I getting this error ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to import anything to access the native APIs. So to use `android.view` you'd just call it in your app like this:

`const x = new android.view.ViewGroup.... // or whatever you're accessing`

Comment: That works but with making a little trick as I am using Angular. I had to declare android as any variable before the component and then using it without making any reference. Thanks for your help

Comment: You're just bypassing that ts doesn't know what android is. Nativescript provides typings for the native APIs if you add the dev dependency: tns-platform-declarations to your project then you get tooling support in TS for native APIs. Hope that helps your experience :)

Answer (score 0):

As per Brad Martin response, there is no need to make any import. To use it in angular environment, add this line before the component declaration.

```
declare var android :any;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the answer ( which also answered my issue ) there are two things to note:

- The native variable that you can use `android`
- The one that you import from `import { android } from "@nativescript/core/application";`

when I used as the answer suggested I run into an issue where it now couldn't find the `addEventListener`  in code: `android.addEventListener`

So eventually I wrote something like this to differentiate between these two variables

```
import {
  android as Android,         <= aliased android => Android
  AndroidActivityEventData,
  AndroidApplication } from '@nativescript/core/application';

Android.addEventListener(AndroidApplication.activityCreatedEvent, (event: AndroidActivityEventData) => {
  event.activity.getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(android.view .View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
});
```